# Grant Anonymous User access to click start workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, workflow

I apologize up front if this has been answered and I just can't find it.

I need to be able to grant all Anonymous users access to start workflows. "click the physical start button for a workflow" (I don't have / can't use Visual Studios)

Site: List what variables it needs.
Workflow: Sends an email with variables to specified email address
(No task or list is being updated or is involved)

I have created a special Anonymous account on the server and gave it rights to this action (tested and works while logged in as the user).

I set IIS to run all Anonymous access as this user.

I have warped and published this workflow from SharePoint designer as the Anonymous user account I created. (IUSRS did not work either)

I am using SharePoint Foundation 2013 (fully patched)

I am using SharePoint Designer 2013

I have ran this command on the server via PowerShell:

```
stsadm -o setproperty -pn declarativeworkflowautostartonemailenabled -pv true
```

---------------------------------Update--------------------------------------

I am pretty sure this can not be done in case someone else has the same question. I ended up creating a sub site within the IIS of my SharePoint server. I gave the site it's own domain name and set a link to it from my SharePoint anonymous site. I then hand coded the interactive form I needed in HTML. I set it up that when they click the submit button it sent the data to php (which had to be installed on the server as a feature) and then the php converted it into a pdf (using fpdf). I then set php to save the pdf to a folder on the server and I made a list on sharepoint for these files. I then mapped that sharepoint list to a mapped drive on the server. I set up a Task on the server to auto move all pdf's in the folder to the mapped drive. Then I set SharePoint to email the correct department the that a new object had been added to the list. Hope this helps anyone that had the same issue as I did.